# lighttpd rewrite-once rule isn't working

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

I just got some problems serving static files via Lighttpd.

Here's what I would want to do:
`www.example.ch` is my domain.
If a call comes to `www.example.ch/static/.....css`
then I want to reroute it and actually serve the file from `static.example.ch/files/....css` (see my url.rewrite-once rule).

Somehow this just doesn't work. Am I missing something completely?

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(^|\.)example\.ch$" {
fastcgi.server = (
    "/django.fcgi" => (
        "main" => (
            "socket" => env.HOME + "/webqs/webqs.sock",
            "check-local" => "disable",
        )
    ),
)
alias.url = (
    "/media" => env.HOME + "/webqs/media",
)

url.rewrite-once = (
    "^(/media.*)$" => "$1",
    "^/favicon\.ico$" => "/media/favicon.ico",
    "^(/static.*)$" => "http://static.example.ch/files/$1",
    "^(/.*)$" => "/django.fcgi$1",
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the regular expression `"^(/static.*)$"` it looks like `$1` is going to contain `/static/...css`. Is there a `static/` directory under your `files/` directory? If not, try changing the regular expression to something like:

```
"^/static/(.*)$"
```

This should match everything after `/static/` but won't also include the string `/static/`.